# How to Configure DotNet Security Source Code Tool Roslyn Security Guard

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

The Roslyn analyzers can be run from Visual Studio by lauching a new build with this extension enabled. 
More : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilippeArteau.RoslynSecurityGuard

How to Configure this extension enabled to visual studio 2005

Anyone Good resource link please share and any other tool DotNet Source Code Review Open Source Tools

Comment: First, this is off-topic. Please read [ask]. Second, it is impossible to add a VS2015 add-in to VS2005. There have been several major releases in the middle, you need to upgrade if you want to use c# 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written in the link it is for visual studio 2015 and higher.